# How to get XML/TXT attachments from diverse email sources in PHP?

Tags: php, email, smtp, attachment, mime

Once the SMTP/MIME text is obtained, it is hard to tell how complex it can be to parse/handle emails coming from all kind of random SMTP/MIME programs.

For the particular pose of this question, obtaining header information is completly irrelevant. Only attachments are needed.

¿Is out there any bullet proof solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a MIME parser to process MIME data. In PHP, the [Mailparse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php) extension can do this for you. It's a fairly basic library, so a wrapper like [php-mime-mail-parser](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) can greatly simplify things. In any case, assuming Mailparse, the basic outline of the process is the following: load/parse the email, then enumate all parts and subparts where the following conditions are met:

- The `Content-Disposition` header for the part is `attachment`.
- The decoded `filename` parameter of the `Content-Dispositon` header ends with the literal `.xml` or `.txt`. Alternatively, you can rely on the `Content-Type` header for type detection (`text/XML` and `text/plain`, respectively), but that will be less reliable, because it depends on the email sender finding out the right MIME type for the attached document.

Once the attachments parts are found, they can be decoded from MIME representation using the PHP-provided functions for BASE64 or quoted-printable decoding.

Comment: Can Mailparse be installed externaly? I have WHM, and i prefer not to mess with that, as it is not in the built in WHM options, and just put the library in a folder.

Comment: @mikl: I'm not familiar with WHM, but from what I gather the PHP Extension Manager is shipped with it. `/scripts/phpextensionmgr` with the `install` parameter should help installing an extension (again, just a tip).

Comment: Ops, just did it. Went to Software/Module Installers/PHP Pecl, and the rest is pretty intuitive.